# How to convert raw pulse sensor data into actual pulse?

Tags: signal-analysis, measurement

I've built a simple device, which sends readings from a [pulse sensor](http://pulsesensor.myshopify.com/pages/pulse-sensor-amped-arduino-v1dot1) to a PC.

I get these [data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11776689/2013_06_02_pulse_sensor_data.ods):

[image: Pulse sensor data]

What technique or algorithm can I use in order to calculate the pulse rate (beats per minute) from these data?

**Update 1 (03.06.2013 21:01 MSK):** The time series represents my heart beat during approx. 3 minutes. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse#Normal_pulse_rates), adults have a pulse rate **between 60 and 100** beats per minute.

**Update 2 (09.06.2013 23:53 MSK):** [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11776689/2013_06_09_pulse/2013_06_09_pulse_sensor_data1.zip) you can find signal values, which were measured 1000 times per second during approx. 5 minutes.

Comment: Do you know what a Fourier transform is, and/or how to implement it?

Comment: What do you consider a "pulse" ? To my eyes, the signal is a DC value with spiky noise.

Comment: @PeterK. "Pulse" is the number of heart beats per minute. The signal comes from a pulse sensor (every 10 milliseconds I measure the voltage of an analog input pin - these values are shown in the diagram).

Comment: @ZettaSuro I know about Fourier transform, but I never implemented it myself. What is the easiest way to implement it in Java (some library) ?

Comment: I think we need some more information. If I look at the data, I notice that the peaks have very different durations. Can they all be considered as one beat or, in other words, is there a maximum time for what can be considered a single beat? Otherwise, wouldn't some simple thresholding do the job?

Comment: [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java) may help. I've never done a Fourier transform in Java, myself, so I can't say much about it.

Comment: Do you expect that the underlying signal is periodic? It's not apparent from looking at the data whether it is or not. I don't know too much about heart rhythms to know whether the rate is short-term stable enough to get good results from Fourier analysis. Also, you probably want to sample faster than 100 Hz; consider the case where your heart rate exceeds your sample rate, where you would miss pulses.

Comment: @JasonR See update 1. An adult's pulse rate is between 60 and 100 beats per minute.

Comment: Yes, but what do you consider a valid pulse? How wide should it be? There are some very narrow "spikes".  How high should it be? There are some places where there are lots of low-valued "spikes".  What do you call a valid pulse?

Comment: I think it would help understanding your problem if you showed a more zoomed-in graph, so as to show more of the shape of a single pulse. If the data in this plot were all you had it would indeed be hard to tell from noise, but from what you've said you have a lot more samples per pulse than currently shown.

Comment: @KevinReid I intend to get a new sample of data with a higher frequency (i. e. I will read the voltage every single millisecond) tomorrow or during the weekend. Then, I'll post these new data here.

Comment: @KevinReid Regarding "zoomed-in graph": In order to get this, just open the spreadsheet with the data ( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11776689/2013_06_02_pulse_sensor_data.ods ).